# Redefine yarn.application.classpath value

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with a hadoop 2.4.0 single node cluster. When i execute `yarn classpath` on console, gives me this:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
```

As you can see, the first value is repeated three times. I looked for a way to redefine or reset this. The only way, as far as i know, it's redefining a property in `yarn-site.xml`, like this:

```
 <property>
    <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
     <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
        <value>
        $HADOOP_CONF_DIR, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, $HADO$
     </value>
  </property>
```

But `yarn.application.classpath` remains the same, without changes, even if i stop every process of hadoop and start them all again. What other option do i have? i'm doing something wrong here?

UPDATE:
I have defined the value of $HADOOP_CONF_DIR in hadoop-env.sh, as:

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"}`

Comment: check the place where you are setting `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`, you might be setting that multiple places.. The $HADOOP_CONF_DIR is added by the bin/hadoop script to the front of the path.

Comment: i'm setting it on `hadoop-env.sh`:
`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"}`